# How to fill imageview's background color like a progressbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a png image something like below and I need to fill its background color according to its capacity.

For example if tank has oil %100 percent of its capacity, background should be yellow , if has %25 , background should be %25 percent yellow and %75 transparent.

Assume that this is a healthbar in a game.

[image]

this is what i have in my layout, just a simple imageview in a linearlayout.
Is there any way to achieve this using animation, clip or something ?

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivOilTank"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/oilTank"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution,

Since I am not interested in **using dp for width property**, i looked for another solution. **If you want to use dp directly check Shadab Ansari's answer** which gave me a clue.

### frameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flOil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <View
                android:id="@+id/progress_view"
               android:background="#fc12d108"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivOil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/oilTank"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            </ImageView>
        </FrameLayout>
```

### Code

```
                ViewTreeObserver vto = ivRate.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener(){
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        ivRate.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        widthTank = ivRate.getMeasuredWidth();//get the width of the imageView which has oilTank image as dp.
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = prgrs.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.width = (int) (widthTank / (new Random().nextInt(4) + 2));//calculate a width for view which is going to fill background color, random was user for testwill be using desired value.
                        prgrs.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Before using widthTank variable , onPreDraw method **has to be called** so be sure that it is called otherwise **it will not be assigned**.

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout xml to contain-

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/percent_highlight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@mipmap/oilTank"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Now wherever you want to highlight the certain percentage of the image -

```
View highlight = findViewById(R.id.percent_highlight);

highlight.setBackgroundResource(<Color_id>);//Any color you want to set

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = highlight.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = (int) (dpToPixel(150) * 25 / 100.0f);//If you want to set 25%
        highlight.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

where  `dpToPixel()`  converts dp to pixels -

```
public int dpToPixel(float dp) {
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
    }
```

Comment: ı need to use match_parent property for framelayout i don't want to use android:layout_width="150dp". But i think i can use you formula. I need to to get a view's width dp programmatically? Then i might use it instead of 150.

Comment: Sure. you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this example 
    https://github.com/fanrunqi/WaveProgressView  or https://github.com/rathodchintan/Percentage-wise-Image-Filling
    this is the best way to fill image